# Python's Subprocess removing Mysql columns and spacing

Tags: python, mysql, bash, subprocess

Specifically, I am using:

```
Python 2.4.3 (#1, May 24 2008, 13:47:28) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)] on linux2
```

I am trying to get the raw result of a mysql query with the column names and borders. Here is the raw command being run in bash:

```
[root@machine ~]# mysql -u root -e 'show databases;'
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| dbA                |
| dbB                |
| dbC                |
+--------------------+
```

I am having trouble storing this value into a variable in Python:

```
import subprocess

cmd_array = ["mysql", "-u", "root", "-e", "show databases"]

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_array)
raw_data = p.communicate()[0]

# Console outputs:
# +--------------------+
# | Database           |
# +--------------------+
# | dbA                |
# | dbB                |
# | dbC                |
# +--------------------+
#
# raw_data is None

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_array, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
rawData = p.communicate()[0]
print rawData

# Console outputs:
# Database
# dbA
# dbB
# dbC
#
# rawData is "Database\ndbA\ndbB\ndbC"
```

What is the best way to store the pretty printed version of the mysql output in a python variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-t`:

```
p = check_output(["mysql" ,"-u" ," root", "-t" ,"-e",  'show databases;'])
print(p)

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| world              |
+--------------------+
```

You can also use `check_output` to store the output.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql` operates differently depending on whether it is being called from a console (pseudo-terminal, pty) or being called from another program. When called from another program, it is purposefully terse for easier parsing. One way to think about it is that

```
"Database\ndbA\ndbB\ndbC"
```

*is* the raw result and

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| dbA                |
| dbB                |
| dbC                |
+--------------------+
```

is a pretty-printed result for people.

I have no idea what a *"column visible string"* is, but if you want to process the data in your program, you got the easily parsed result you want.

If you really do want the fancy print version, you can use the `pexpect` or `pty` modules to emulate a terminal. Here's an example:

```
>>> import pexpect
>>> import subprocess
>>> child = pexpect.spawn('mysql -e "show databases"')
>>> child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
0
>>> print child.before
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

Comment: What I mean by 'column visible string' is I want to be able to see the borders. I figured that because mysql already displays the pretty printed string when called with the same command in bash, the python equivalent would be trivial.

Comment: I updated to mention other modules. You example without `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` displays on the screen the way you want. You want to display and process it?

Comment: I'd like to store the pretty printed result into a variable. My example without `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` directly dumps the output into stdout and I cannot capture it easily in my *raw_data* variable.

Comment: I've added an example using `pexpect`. Hope it's what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `mysql` uses `isatty()` to determine if STDOUT is a terminal which then modifies the output.

I can get the table borders by specifying the `--table` or `-t` option:

`cmd_array = ["mysql", "-t", "-u", "root", "-e", "show databases"]`